# In this table, how do I only return people who have had Coffee or Beer but NEVER ever had Shake or Water?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, teradata

```
Column A | Column B (Beverage)
Andres      Coffee
Erica       Coffee
David       Beer
Tyler       Beer
Tyler       Beer
Andres      Shake
Erica       Coffee
Erica       Coffee
David       Beer
David       Coffee
Tyler       Water
Tyler       Shake
```

Then I'd only want to see Erica and David (because they only had Coffee and/or Beer), but NOT Andres because he had Shake; and not Tyler because he had Shake and Water both.

Comment: You need [Shake or Water] or [Shake and Water] - your subject doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
             WHERE ColumnA = T.ColumnA
             AND ColumnB IN ('Coffee','Beer'))
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
               WHERE ColumnA = T.ColumnA
               AND ColumnB IN ('Shake','Water'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use not exists to exclude and distinct to show the unique columnA

```
SELECT distinct ColA    FROM YourTable AS T
WHERE ColumnB IN ('Coffee','Beer')
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable T2
               WHERE T2.ColumnA = T.ColumnA
               AND T2.ColumnB IN ('Shake','Water'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple GROUP BY.
No need for correlated sub-queries (Exists / Not Exists).

```
select      ColumnA    
from        mytable
group by    ColumnA
having      count (case when ColumnB in ('Coffee','Beer' ) then 1 end > 0
        and count (case when ColumnB in ('Water ','Shake') then 1 end = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select columnA from t where columnB in ('Coffee','Beer')
      minus
   select columnA from t where columnB in ('Shake')
      minus
   select columnA from t where columnB in ('Shake','Water')
   having count(distinct columnB)=2
;
```